# Sequence sum [easy question]

Tags: sequences-and-series

I had this issue, when I tried to find the sum of this sequence 
$$U_n= 4n+1$$
And when I put the formula 
$$S_n= \frac{n}{2}(a+l)$$
And I've found that 
$$S_n = 2n^2+n$$
Whereas I know it should be 
$$S_n=2n^2-n$$

Comment: $S_n = \frac{n(a+l)}{2}$ or $S_n = \frac n{2(a+l)}$?

Comment: $S_n =\frac {n}{2}(a+l) $ Where a is U0 and l is Un

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\sum_{k=1}^n(4k+1)=4\sum_{k=1}^nk+\sum_{k=1}^n1=4\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}+n=2n^2+3n.$$ Using your expression it is $a=5$ and $l=4n+1.$ Thus $$S_n=\frac{n}{2}(4n+6)=2n^2+3n.$$

But

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(4k+1)=4\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}1=4\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}+n=2n^2-n.$$

Using your expression it is $a=1$ and $l=4n-3.$ Thus $$S_n=\frac{n}{2}(4n-2)=2n^2-n,$$ where $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_k.$

Comment: oh thank u :), that was very helpful